# Why doesn't Python throw a NameError when you invoke a function which has not yet been defined in a function definition

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose this minimal example:

```
In [1]: !cat add_ones.py  
def two():
    return one() * 2
def one():
    return 1
print(two())
```

This will successfully return 2.

I am confused here about:
When I invoke `two()`, it's nested function `one()` within has not been defined.

Why doesn't `print(two())` report:

> `NameError: name one is not defined`.

I assume that in the correct order we should place `one()` to the top.

```
In [1]: !cat add_ones.py  
def one():
    return 1
def two():
    return one() * 2

print(two())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one is not nested.

If it was, it would be indented inside the *two* function.

Python reads and loads both functions before he reached the last line.

In this code the functions order is meaningless.